# Get binding point of sampler/image in shader

Tags: opengl

I have an image and a sampler declared in a shader as follow

```
layout(binding = 5) uniform isampler2D heightmap;
layout(binding = 3) uniform writeonly uimage2D info;
```

Which are correctly bound using the following code

```
glBindTextureUnit(5, heightmapId);
glBindImageTextures(3, 1, &infoId);
```

For introspection purposes, I am trying to retrieve the binding points of these objets, 5 and 3, but I didn't find any way to do this for uniforms. Is it possible using the API?

I first tried to use glGetProgramResourceIndex, since it worked with storage buffers, but it doesn't the results are get are incorrect, as if the explicit binding was ignored.

I then looked at glGetProgramResourceiv, but the binding related enums are only available for storage buffers and atomic counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `binding` value for uniforms of opaque types is, from the perspective of the OpenGL API, the uniform's *value*. You set it by using `glProgramUniform1i`.

As such, you query it by querying the value of the uniform with `glGetUniformiv`.